# jquery post request: how to indicate browser activity

Tags: jquery, post

I am using `$.post` to send a json structure built out of user input:

```
$.post(
    url1,
    {'input': JSON.stringify(input)},
    function(data) {
        if (data['status']) window.location.href = url2;
        else window.location.href = url1;
    }
);
```

A redirection always occurs after the post. My problem is that a browser seems to be inactive during the post and does not show any activity (i.e. loading progress) until the redirection starts, which results in circa 1 second when seemingly nothing is happening. By activity I just mean the standard ways of browsers to tell a user that it is loading a page (e.g. progress circle shown on my firefox tabs). Is there any way to invoke this standard behaviour as soon as the posting starts?

**EDIT:** Some people were asking why I don't simply use the standard form submission. Well it is because the data I need to send are kinda complex to build and I don't know if something like this can be done by standard (not-ajax) means. This is how I build the data:

```
var input = [];
$('.shopCat > p > input').each(function() {
      input.push({
        'id': $(this).closest('div').attr('id'),
        'name': $(this).val(),
        'parent': $(this).closest('div').attr('data-parent');
    });
});
```

Is it possible to build and post such data with a standard post form? (So i am actually asking two questions now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't force the browser to appear busy. But you can set the cursor to busy

```
$(document).css('cursor','wait');
$.post(
url1,
{'input': JSON.stringify(input)},
function(data) {
    if (data['status']) window.location.href = url2;
    else window.location.href = url1;

}
);
```

Although it might be better **to not use ajax**, just use normal form submission, since you chose to redirect afterwards anyways.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a packaged means of doing this in jQuery or javascript. You can imagine there are a lot of scenarios where people choose to display a waiting icon. Just show your wait content before posting and then in the callback hide it.

```
$('#waiting').show(); //show waiting icon or whatever
$.post(
    url1,
    {'input': JSON.stringify(input)},
    function(data) {
        $('#waiting').hide();  //hide it on callback
        if (data['status']) window.location.href = url2;
        else window.location.href = url1;
    }
);
```

If you have a specific idea of what you want then let us know. Like you want a modal window, or a specific div to be covered up. A progress bar, one of those circle dealies, please wait text, etc, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I'll probably use this approach as accessing "standard browser resources" from javascript is probably not possible. Please if you can, see my edited post...i am curious if my approach is not wrong from the beginning...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jquery blockui plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com) to indicate that some async operation is in progress... just call blockUI before making post, and unblockUI in your callback. it doesn't neccessary blocks UI...take a look at [examples](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos) here and check out "Growl" option or something that is appropriate for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

If a redirection always happens, why are you using a AJAX request instead of posting the form to the server and redirecting on the server side? You would also get a better performance from that since you save a request.